# How can i delete HTML element in vba excel

Tags: html, excel, vba

I am working on a code that uses VBA-Excel to navigate to a website and automate a daily task i do . Having said that , am stuck in between of trying to delete an html element . The following js code works perfect i.e. :-

```
var elmnt = document.getElementById("foregxyz");
elmnt.remove();
```

How could i make the above 2 lines of js code in vba excel ?

I tried the following but with no result . Please help , thanks in advance .

```
Sub DailyTask()

    Dim ie As InternetExplorer
    Set ie = New InternetExplorerMedium
    Dim url As String
    Dim elementToBeDeleted As String
    url = "https://www.example.com"

    ie.Visible = True
    ie.Navigate url

    While ie.Busy
    DoEvents
    Wend

    ie.Document.getElementsByTagName("select")("toDOList").Value = "TEST1"
    ie.Document.getElementsByTagName("select")("scheduleDate").Value = "TEST2"
    ie.Document.getElementsByTagName("select")("descriptionTask").Value = "TEST3"

    'Many more of data entry until submitting the form works fine . 

    elementToBeDeleted = ie.Document.getElementById("xyz") 
    Call DeleteTagById(elementToBeDeleted)

    Set ie = Nothing
    End Sub

    Function DeleteTagById(elementToBeDeleted As String) As String

    On Local Error GoTo MyError

    Dim HTMLDoc As HTMLDocument
    Dim Node As IHTMLDOMNode

    If elementToBeDeleted = "" Then GoTo MyExit

    Set HTMLDoc = New HTMLDocument
    Set Node = HTMLDoc.getElementById("xyz") 'Node always equals to nothing , why ? hence i get stuck here and cant move further.

    'If Node Is Nothing Then GoTo MyExit
    Node.ParentNode.RemoveChild Node      'this line gives me run time error 91 object variable or with block variable not set . 

MyExit:
    Set Node = Nothing
    Set HTMLDoc = Nothing
    Exit Function
MyError:
    'Handle Error
    Resume MyExit

End Function
```

Comment: I've noticed odd things in this realm related to the version of Office being used. Which version are you running, and is it site-installed or 365?

Comment: By "this realm" I mean parsing nodes...I was working with XML.

Comment: @MBB70 its the standard 2016 and not 365 . The version is 16.0.4266.1001. The document im referring is related to html and not XML . I'm only trying to achieve to delete an html element for instance the table tag .

Comment: @John...in my situation, the node contained data when using Excel 2013 but not when using 2016 or 365. I know that's not very helpful to you in your particular situation...I was just hoping to give you some kind of lead. You might also want to use Option Explicit at the top of your module to see if that reveals any compile issues. Also, look into Early and Late Binding of your `ie` variable....sometimes using the other binding type can have unexpectedly good results....worth a try.